# Wp_Query for custom post type not showing properly

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a Wp_Query to loop through my custom post types, however it seems to be wrong but I can't see the mistake. After the post thumbnail, I can see (">) as if some tag wasn't closed correctly, but i have tried a few different things to no avail.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
         "post_type" => "piso"
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>

<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="pisos-grid-item-wrap">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array('width'=>'270') ); ?>">
        </a>

        <h1> <?php echo $precio ?> € </h1>
        <h2> <?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
        <h3> <?php echo $donde ?> </h3>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

A screenshot of the problem
[image: Wp?Query problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) function returns the img tag itself so you don't need to insert the tag yourself.

You should change your code to the following:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array('width'=>'270') ); ?>
</a>
```

Also you can check if the post has a thumbnail or not using [has_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) function. Change your code to the following:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array('width'=>'270') ); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That does work but the post thumbnail does not respect the 'width'=>'270' and instead is 1000px wide. I have fixed it with css but yea. Thank you for your answer.